# What is the proper way to use descendant in XPath

Tags: xpath

I am trying to find all DIV elements have the attribute widget-name and a descendant span tag that have a title attribute.

This is what I am trying.

```
//div[@widget-name and descendant::span[@title]]"
```

This seems to almost work but it is missing one element in the Nodes Collection it returns.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind.

This is what I needed:

```
//div[@widget-name and descendant::span[@class='title']]
```

OK - take it back.
This is not the complete answer.
I am now trying to tweak this to where it returns all except where title is not equal to some text:

```
//div[@widget-name and descendant::span[@class='title' and [text()[contains(., '{someTextToKeep}'
```

Anyone see why this would be invalid XPath?

Final answer is:

```
//div[@widget-name and descendant::span[@class='title' and text()[not(contains(., 'someTextToKeep'))]]]"
```

Comment: Looks good, but you could simplify `text()[not(contains(., 'someTextToKeep'))]` to `not(contains(., 'someTextToKeep'))`

Answer (score 0):

This XPath should return all `div`'s that:

- has a `widget-name` attribute
- has a descendant `span` element (used [abbreviated syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev)) that:

  - has a `class` attribute with the value 'title'
  - contains the text 'someTextToKeep' (if you want to exclude spans with certain text, wrap the `contains()` in `not()`.

XPath:

```
//div[@widget-name and .//span[@class='title'][contains(.,'someTextToKeep')]]
```